# Zoom screen share no longer works with Wayland after August update

Tags: wayland, zoom

There was an update from Zoom in early August 2023 (I forget the exact date) that has broken screen share completely for me and partly for a colleague who also uses Linux.

We both have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS machines, reimaged onto Dell machines that were originally windows.

I won't write more details because after a search, I thought it might be due to Wayland, and it was.  So I will add my answer here to help others find it.

Answer (score 0):

I was fairly sure the problem was due to Zoom actually building towards X11 as a target, and then they were relying upon the [XWayland compatibility layer](https://www.howtogeek.com/900698/what-is-wayland-on-linux-and-how-is-it-different-from-x/) to fix the problem.

But I couldn't easily figure out how to swap over to X11 and test this out.  Then I ran across [this article on how to switch between them](https://helpdesk.psionline.com/hc/en-gb/articles/13470827149332-How-to-perform-the-switch-from-the-Wayland-display-server-to-Xorg-X11-on-Linux-Ubuntu-22-04-LTS), saw how incredibly easy it was, and wanted to post this for others to more easily discover.

The article says:

- log out
- log back in, *but not all the way*:

  - Click on your user name
  - Before you enter your password, instead click the gear icon on the bottom right
  - The gear icon lets you choose either Wayland (just called Ubuntu) or X11 (called Ubuntu on Xorg)
  - Then type in your password like usual